# How to make vs2010 auto generate method stubs at the end of file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, stubs

I try to auto generate method stub using visual studio's View.ShowSmartTag functionality
[image]

When I choose this option, *Method8* will be placed right after *Method2* but I want to place it after all methods, *Method7* in this case.
Is there any settings for this?

Comment: I doubt it.  Cut/Paste is how I've been doing it.

Comment: It's quite time-consuming action if I use this feature often

Comment: Agreed! But if MS put them all at the bottom, others would complain that they have to scroll all the way down to the bottom to edit/move the method.

Comment: Is it too hard to implement some settings for this? Like one checkbox whether place stubs at the top or at the bottom.

Comment: You could always write your own plug-in and publish it out on codeplex.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After researching I found that I couldn't do that